# Twitter Bootstrap - Drop down menu - Arrows Keys are not working for input tags in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Requirement**

I want to put a login form inside the drowdown menu with username and password field, I am able to do that. all works well except the below issue,

**Issue**

While typing i am not able to use the arrows keys(up/down) in ***firefox*** , this works well when the input is outside the drowdown code. This works fine with other browsers like google crome.

- *Firefox* version is *26*
- Bootstrap version : 3.03
- jquery  1.10

**Question:**

how to resolve this problem, is there an problem with jquery or twiter's js, as it works well when i move the input outside the dropdown

**Fiddle**

here is the fiddle that replicates the same::: http://jsfiddle.net/santoshjoshi/WKU6M/3/

**Code:**

```or-tag-here
    <div id="navbar-example" class="navbar navbar-static">
    <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
        <div class="nav-collapse bs-js-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li id="sign-up-dropdown" class="dropdown closed noshow">
                    <a href="#" id="drop4" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign Up<b class="caret">&nbsp;</b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                        <li role="presentation">
                                <div class="login_dropdown platform-font-1">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal"  action="login" method="POST">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">&#160;</input>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Arrow keys works with the below input but not the one inside drop down -->
<input type="text" class="form-control " id="email1" name="email" placeholder="Email">&#160;</input>
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in Firefox. I usually use ALT + left arrow or ALT + right arrow to move at the beginning or a the end and these shortcuts works.

Comment: Do you want to use up/down arrows to select an auto-complete list entry?

Comment: Ok IF you want to use up/down arrows to select an auto-complete list entry then I can confirm this different behavior for Chrome. And I can confirm A. Wolff's solution solves it for me.

Comment: @ToniTornado i want to use it like an presaved/prefilled auto suggest/complete entries.

Comment: @LeBen, I think this is a bug with bootstrap as the other input type outside the menu works perfectly

Comment: @SantoshJoshi You’re right, I thought there was a preventDefault somewhere but wasn’t able to find it.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like kind of bug to me but as a simple fix, stop propagation of `onkeydown` event:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WKU6M/4/)

```
$('#email').on('keydown',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This works, but The only question is that why autosuggest/complete entries work with the the input outside the dowpdown, and not with the input inside the dropdown. is this really a bug with firefox or twitter's Bootstrap