# <input> element doesn't go to history when <DOWN ARROW> key

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

Usually, when you press the `<DOWN ARROW>` key on an `<input>`, you can access to the last saved values of the `<form>` (useful for remembering username, email) :

[image]

I have a Bootstrap `<input>` for which `<DOWN ARROW>` does not work (it does not show anything), even if *there is a history* (I know this because when I click in the input, I can see a dropdown menu with past values).

**What could be the reason for `<DOWN ARROW>` not showing the past history of a form input?**

---

*Of course, as you have no previously entered input on your browser for this demo page : http://bigpicture.bi/php/test.php , you will not be able to see what happens when `<DOWN ARROW>`, but still the HTML code could be useful to debug :*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="mainnavbar">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="loginsignupmenu">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login / Sign up<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width: 250px; padding:12px 20px;">
                  <form id="loginmenu" method="post" autocomplete="on"> 
                      <input class="form-control logindropdown signup login forgot" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="example@email.com" title="Enter your email or username" autocomplete="on" />
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-logindropdown logindropdown login" id="login" type="submit">Login</button> 
                 </form>                                                    
                </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add autocomplete="on" to your input.

Comment: @Templar I updated the question with code showing an example, but even with `autocomplete="on"`, it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - Drop down menu - Arrows Keys are not working for input tags in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732367/twitter-bootstrap-drop-down-menu-arrows-keys-are-not-working-for-input-tags)

Comment: @showdev : that's right : `$('#email').on('keydown',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});` solved the problem. Topic solved!